Is it legal for someone to grab your hand and "try" to make you sign something without knowing what it is?
My aunt told me to sign something and I asked her what it was she said don't worry about it, then when I refused she grabbed my hand and tried to make me sign it.

There are really 2 questions to be answered here. 1. Is your forced signature valid & binding on you? 2. Has your aunt committed assault on you by grabbing your hand and forcing you to do something you didn't want to do?

This is not legal and your signature would not be binding. (This may be more complicated if you are a minor and she is your legal guardian.)
For example, this legal office talks about how a contract signed under duress is not valid: https://bc-llp.com/if-i-am-forced-to-sign-a-contract-is-it-still-valid/
However, note that the burden of proof may be on you to claim that the signature is not valid; details would vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction.

It is not legal for someone to forcibly attempt to make you sign something without your consent or understanding of what you are signing. Here are some key points to consider:
Consent: In order for a contract or agreement to be legally binding, all parties involved must freely give their consent. Attempting to force someone to sign a document against their will constitutes coercion and invalidates any agreement made.
Understanding: It is essential for all parties to understand the terms and implications of any document they are signing. If someone is pressured or prevented from knowing what they are signing, the agreement may be deemed void due to lack of genuine consent.
Fraud: Deliberately withholding information or misleading someone about the content of a document in order to obtain their signature is fraudulent behavior. This can have serious legal consequences for the person attempting to deceive or manipulate others.
Legal Rights: Every individual has the right to refuse to sign any document they do not fully understand or agree with. No one should be forced or intimidated into signing something against their will

Welcome to Law.SE.  Please take our tour.  And note that GPT answers are not allowed here.
